# Getting multiple pivot tables results together as 1 data set

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following data structure in my laravel application

```
user_comments
    id - integer
    name - string
    created_at - timestamp
 
user_actions
    id - integer
    name - string
    created_at - timestamp
 
users
    id - integer
    name - string
 
user_history
    user_id - integer
    history_id - integer
    history_type - string
```

And my `App\Models\User` contains the following relationships

```php
    /**
     * Get all of the comments that are associated with this user.
     */
    public function comments() : BelongsToMany {
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserComment::class, 'user_history', 'user_id', 'history_id')->where('user_history.history_type', 'comment');
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the actions that are associated with this user.
     */
    public function actions() : BelongsToMany {
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserAction::class, 'user_history', 'user_id', 'history_id')->where('user_history.history_type', 'action');
    }
```

My aim is to be able to get each history type separately when I need it, but then be able to get all of the users history together, as a combined history trail of everything the user has done in the order it was done, so I can loop through and print out a history log.

At the moment the only way I can think of is by getting each of the relationships, merging the collections and sorting by `created_at` `DESC`, which is working fine, but in a perfect world, I would like to make 1 relationship (maybe polymorphic?) that just gets the `actions` and `comments` pivots together as 1 big collection.

As far as i'm aware, I cant `UNION` in the database as the tables have different column counts (and I need all the data from each table).

Is there a way to do this neatly using relationships to get the database to do the legwork, rather than having to get the relationships separately and merge/sort them?

Going forward there will be more pivot relationships like `user_photos`, `user_emails`, etc, so 1 neat way to get them all would be perfect!

Comment: Only laravel calls junction tables that enable many-to-many relationships as pivot tables. The pivot table tag on SO is for the rows-to-columns transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need interact with a pivot table, you can create a pivot model and use it as a normal model, or you can write a DB statement that will get the data. I like the model way better.

```
class UserHistory extends Pivot
{
   // since Pivot extends Model
   // this just a normal model
   // with Pivot specific stuff.
}
```

DB statement can be something like this:

```
DB::select('select * from user_history');
```

Comment: But how can I use the model to get all user history combined into 1 collection? Whats the benefit to this than just writing a function against the user called `allHistory()` which builds and combines the history?

Comment: `UserHistory::get()` `UserHHistory::where('user_id', $userID)->get()`

Comment: But that will only get the pivot table data wont it? Not all of the tables the pivot links to?